# Elasticsearch filtered query for partial field name

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to do a filtered query on elastic search using only partial path for the filed (as opposed to a fully qualified path).

For example, my mapping looks like follows:

```
{
  "library" : {
     "properties":{
        "name" : {
            "type":"string"
        },
        "address" : {
            "properties":{
                "city" : {
                    "type":"string"
                }
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

If I do a filtered query on 'name' field or 'libary.name' field (with a valid value) I get results back as expected. However, if I do a filtered query on 'address.city' or 'city' I don't get any results back; I have to name the tag as 'library.address.city'.

I couldn't find any documentation explaining this behaviour. Any suggestions to make my filtered queries work for 'address.city' similar to how it already works for 'name'?

This works

```
{
  "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "name" : "xyz"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work (or 'address.city' instead)

```
 {
      "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "term": {
                        "city" : "xyz"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: did the solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to `term query`, it is looking for an **exact match**. You are using [object datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) and you should be able to access *city* field with `address.city`.

I created index with your mapping,

```
PUT ob_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "library": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "address": {
          "properties": {
            "city": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then inserted document

```
PUT ob_index/library/11
{
  "name" : "Tesla",
  "address" : {
    "city" : "orlando"
  }
}
```

You can query the city field with `address.city`.

```
GET ob_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "address.city": {
            "value": "orlando"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you the document back, now if you replace *orlando* with *Orlando* then it wont match, You might want to use [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) since your field is `analyzed`. [More](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html) on analysis.

You can also use `query string query` and use `wildcard` for fields

```
GET ob_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["address*"], 
      "query": "orlando"
    }
  }
}
```

This will search in everything inside address object

Hope this helps!